# update based on another query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which identifies the wid and loc_num based on the loc_type

```
select LOC_NUM, WID, loc_type from a  WHERE ROW_WID IN 
(select DISTINCT PLANT_LOC_WID from b) AND loc_type = 'STORAGE_LOC';
```

Right now the wid in table b is getting updated with the loc_type = 'STORAGE_LOC', but i need to update the wid with loc_type = 'PLANT' for that particular loc_num

```
Table A below:-

wid     loc_num    loc_type
884059  038        STORAGE_LOC
881993  038        PLANT
```

All the records in the table `B` with `PLANT_LOC_WID` = 884059 needs to be updated with `PLANT_LOC_WID` = 881993..

tABLE b BELOW:-

```
 WID     
884059
884059
884059
```

tABLE B NEEDS TO GET UPDATED AS

```
 WID 
 881993 
 881993 
 881993
```

Comment: what is the impediment?

Comment: Hi kaushik - I am trying to write a update statement using corelated sub query but that's not working.

Comment: please also include the update query you are using in the question?

Comment: It is messed up. Show the table structure of `Table b`, `Table A`, and  end result you need in `Table b`

Comment: Does Tableb has a column loc_num ?? . If yes. why don't you show it clearly in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Update table b
Set  PLANT_LOC_WID =(select wid from table a where loc_type = 'PLANT');

Answer (score 0):

You can update your like below. You just made the query complex

```
UPDATE A   SET A.PLANT_LOC_WID =
(SELECT NVL(B.ROW_WID,0) FROM  b   WHERE a.LOC_NUM = b.LOC_NUM AND b.LOC_TYPE = 'PLANT')
WHERE WID IN  (select DISTINCT PLANT_LOC_WID    from b) AND loc_type ='STORAGE_LOC'
```

Comment: its not working Rams. I don't have loc_num in A table.

Comment: In the first select query you have mentioned that loc_num??